# Error is occured when I try to build and install Numeric-24.2, anybody, help please me

Tags: 13.10, python

```
vprasopchai@vprasopchai-Aspire-4720Z:~/Downloads/Numeric-24.2$ python setup.py build
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
MA Version 12.2.0
Numeric Version 24.2


vprasopchai@vprasopchai-Aspire-4720Z:~/Downloads/Numeric-24.2$ python setup.py install
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Numeric
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Numeric': Permission denied
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! For future reference, try to avoid things like "anybody, help" in your questions. The whole point of this site is helping people. =D We like questions to concisely describe the problem, and extra stuff like "anybody, help" or "thanks in advance" distracts from the problem at hand. (I know you didn't say "thanks in advance". I'm just giving examples of things not to do.) For more info, have a read of [this page.](http://askubuntu.com/tour)

Answer (score 3):

This link should point you in the right direction:
https://docs.python.org/2/install/

Note: the *Permission denied* error is a reference to privileges. try instead:

```
python setup.py build  
sudo python setup.py install
```

OR

another alternative, if you choose not to use root permissions:

```
python setup.py build  
python setup.py install --user
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I use the line with --user my problem is solved already.

Comment: You're welcome, please check-off the answer if it was useful. Glad I could help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I've noticed you're new here, so I thought I'd mention a few "style" pointers. Your answer fits the guidelines pretty well, so keep up the good work. However, we try to avoid saying unnecessary things like "Hope this helps". The aim is to provide precise answers to questions, so anything extra is distracting. Think of this as a bit like "question and answer wikipedia" rather than a forum. I hope you enjoy your time on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the heads-up, and the welcome.

Comment: You don't need to use sudo to build the package, only to install it.